# Game Theory - trying to find game name by description

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

My hobby AI research have led me to a thorethical game of particular design. As design is pretty simple, I'm almost sure that such game has well-known name and tons of research already done around it. Unfortunately my systematic schoolarship of game theory was almost ten years ago and I can't recall it by myself. Can anyone enlighten me, please?

This is N-player game and moves are simultaneous. Each round player can bid (from zero up to predefined maximum) either on red or on black. Color accumulating bigger sum of bids wins. Sum of bids on loosing color is shared amongst winners proportionally to their bids. Players can communicate between rounds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a modified version of [this game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Competition_game) here on the Wikipedia article on Nash equilibrium. It is similar, only the winning condition is inverted, and this is a 2-player game, not n-player. The principles are entirely the same though.

Quoting from the page:

> Both players simultaneously choose an integer from 0 to 3 and they both win the smaller of the two numbers in points. In addition, if one player chooses a larger number than the other, then he/she has to give up two points to the other.

Comment: Thank you for direction, but I can't mark this as acceptable answer, unfortunately. An hour of trying to imagine some sort of isomorphism between this competition game and my case have not produced any result. Looks like that differencies are too big, game I described is only starting to make sense with 3 players and more - from what I see it's mostly about forming clique with shared secret strategy that other players can't predict.

Comment: @DoktorDiagoras yes I suspected so. Some more searching hasn't yet turned up anything either. Where did you come across this?

Comment: Well, it would be very hard to explain without writing full paper on my research. In broad lines this have rised from idea to place number of independent learning actors into environment that rewards both cooperative and competitive behavior simultaneously.